# Protocols, domains, and ports must match on my chat Application

Tags: cross-domain, socket.io, chat

Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.prolisoft.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.snehalcreation.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. socket.io.js:2706
(anonymous function) socket.io.js:2706
V socket.io.js:2706 h socket.io.js:2706 f socket.io.js:2706

Our chat application is installed on "http://www.snehalcreation.com" and our server is on other domain "http://www.prolisoft.com". So might be due cross domain our chat application not working properly.

So please help regarding cross domain,protocols & ports access problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript)